# log4j: configuration causes duplicate messages to be written to the log file

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using log4j 1.2.17.  I've tried to configure log4j.properties so that messages are written to the console and a log file.  Writing messages to the console works fine.  I only see one entry being written to the log file per log message.  However, duplicate messages are being written to the log file.  In other words, for every INFO written to the log, it is written twice.  I tried using additivity to control this, but it doesn't seem to work.  What would I need to do to correct this behavior?

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, R, C

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.base}/logs/storefrontPing.log
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %t [%-5p] %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.additivity.R = false

log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n
log4j.appender.C.Target=System.out
log4j.additivity.C = false

log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR, R
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR, C

log4j.logger.com.aktion.storefront.ping=INFO, C
log4j.logger.com.aktion.storefront.ping=INFO, R
```

REVISED

I changed my log4j.properties file to the following.  Now I get the log message written to the console, but nothing written to the log file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, R, C

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.base}/logs/storefrontPing.log
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %t [%-5p] %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.Append = true

log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n
log4j.appender.C.Target=System.out

log4j.logger.com.aktion.storefront.ping=INFO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appender additivity is not configured on the appender but on the logger (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#additivity)

Since you already added your appenders to the root logger, you don't need to add them again later on. You should define your additional loggers just with the desired log levels:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR

log4j.logger.com.aktion.storefront.ping=INFO
log4j.logger.com.aktion.storefront.ping=INFO
```

And, since you do not change the log level from the root logger to the org.apache logger, you may even omit those:

```
#log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR
#log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR

log4j.logger.com.aktion.storefront.ping=INFO
log4j.logger.com.aktion.storefront.ping=INFO
```

Comment: I tried your changes.  Now I get a log INFO message written to the console, but nothing written to the log file.  I included a revised log4j.properties file is now included in my question.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: My bad.  The issue was how I had my local Tomcat server defined within Eclipse.  This is working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`additivity` should be set on logger level, not appender, so in your case remove following lines:

```
log4j.additivity.R = false
log4j.additivity.C = false
```

and add:

```
log4j.additivity.org.apache=false
```